# youtube api differences between usr, channel and videos

Tags: youtube-api

I am starting to research the youtube api and trying to understand the hierarchy in objects within the api. I see that there was a version (v2) deprecated in 2014 that maybe adding to the confusion. When I think of channel, I think of an author/user that has many videos under his / her account. But when one looks at an example, what is a playlist vs channel vs user?

eg. these seem to be the same https://www.youtube.com/user/BlueXephos vs https://www.youtube.com/BlueXephos

Comment: no difference, maybe it's a shorcut to share more quickly your channel :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand:

Channel - a group of videos and playlists from a user that can be searched and filtered. A user account can have different channels.

User - Alias for main channel. https://www.youtube.com/user/BohemianEagle/ same as https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpnjlvS2zxhbNJuGNo_TxkQ

Playlist - a group of videos from a user that is meant to be played in a certain order. Cannot be searched/filtered.